# To parse a frame in a HTML file with PYTHON which has java script code embedded

Tags: python, html

I am trying to access a secured HTTPS website where right click is disabled. with python, I parsed the HTML source code and it has frames which inturn has a HTML file embedded ("RSLogin.html"). I need to access the frame so as to further access the elements (textbox, click buttons) in that frame. I don't know how to parse the contents of "RSLogin.html" embedded in the frame. I am new to PYTHON. Can someone give me a helping hand? There are few similar posts that are still unanswered. 
I tried beautifulSoup package but still didnt get a solution.

```
</script>
    </head>
        <frameset border="false" frameborder="O" framespacing="0" rows="0,*" cols="*">
            <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="frame_rsafp" src="rsa_flash_cookie.html" noresize="true" scrolling="no">
        <frameset border="false" frameborder="O" framespacing="0" rows="*,30" cols="*">
            <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="login_page" src="RSLogin.html" noresize="true" scrolling="yes">
            <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="footer" src="footer.html" noresize="true" scrolling="no">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
```

Comment: Don't download the HTML document with the frameset but the one called _RSLogin.html_ and process _that_.

Comment: I did a switch_to_frame() and read the contents of RSLogin.html.